# Calculating derivatives with backpropagation using Sutskever's technique

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

In ["TRAINING RECURRENT NEURAL NETWORK"](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~ilya/pubs/ilya_sutskever_phd_thesis.pdf) by Ilya Sutskever, there's the following technique for calculating derivatives with backpropagation in feed-forward neural networks.

The network has l hidden layers, l+1 weight matrices and b+1 bias vectors.

"Forward" stage:

[image]

"Backwards" stage:

[image]

**Isn't there an index problem with l+1? for example, in the forward stage we calculate z_l+1 but return z_l.**

(Since this is such a major paper, I guess I'm missing something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem, some of the indices start at 0 (the variable z for instance), and some start at 1 (the variable x). Follow the algorithm as laid out more carefully, try writing it out by hand explicitly for say l=4.

Comment: I still don't understand why we output z_l when the last calculated entry was z_l+1. Also, it seems z's length is (l+2), since we access z_0 and z_l+1. Is that correct?

Comment: It looks like the output is a typo, yes.  z has a length of (l+2) yes, but its more for notational convince - treating the input x as an "activation" (z_0) rather than a special case.

Comment: OK, so it is a typo after all. Is this also the case in the other direction? (we initialize dz_l but inside the loop use dz_l+1)

Comment: it looks like that one is also a typo. All three z_l should be z_(l+1), and then the backwards z_l gets computed on line 4.